# How to get the results from two tables for the same column values?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Please provide the solution for how to get the values from two table with matching column values,Not with foreiegn key id.

EX:

```
Tablea      
Employee name   DEP      Grade
Hari            Science   A
ram                Maths    B

Tableb      
Employee name   other Fee   Tuition
Hari                 1000   200
ram                  3000   100
```

Expected result:

```
Employee name   other Fee   Tuition  DEP       GRADE
Hari                 1000   200       science   a
ram                  3000   100        Maths    b
```

There is no foreign key relationship with both the tables. Only the column values(hari,ram) are matching with both the tables.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a foreign key in order to perform a join, just matching values:

```
SELECT a.name, other_fee, tuition, dep, grade
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with join to fetch the data

```
SELECT b.name, b.other_fee, b.tuition, a.dep, a.grade
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON b.name = a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following SQL.

`select a.[Employee name],[other Fee],[Tuition],[DEP],[GRADE]
from Tablea a join tableb b on a.[Employee name]=b.[Employee name]`